# Why does my Java calculator pause at loop?

Tags: java

After `calculator()` has ran, my program pauses...unless I enter an input to unpause the program. Then it continues to run and it prints out. However the input that I entered earlier to unpause the program is stored into `answer`. Please read my comments in the code to have a better understanding. If you still don't understand then feel free to copy the code to see what I am talking about.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat){
            calculator(); //-Program pauses after this has ran.
            System.out.println("Do you wish to repeat(y/n)?"); // This does not appear unless I enter an input.
            String answer = userInput.next(); //The input that I entered earlier to unpause the program gets stored into answer.

                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){ 
                    repeat = true;
                } else { repeat = false;}}} //Program terminates here because the input that I used to unpause the program isn't "y".
```

Full code below:

```
package calculatorAttempt;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CalculatorV2 {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void calculator(){

    System.out.print(":");

    if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
        int num1 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print(":");
        String inString = userInput.next();
        System.out.print(":");
        int num2 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("=");

            if (inString.equals("+")){
                System.out.print(num1+num2);}

            if (inString.equals("-")){
                System.out.print(num1-num2);}

            if (inString.equals("*")||(inString.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))){
                System.out.print(num1+num2);}

            if (inString.equals("/")){
                float intTofloat = (float)num1/num2;
                System.out.println(intTofloat);}    }//If Integer


    if (userInput.hasNextFloat()){
        float num1 = userInput.nextFloat();
        System.out.print(":");
        String inString = userInput.next();
        System.out.print(":");
        float num2 = userInput.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("=");

            if (inString.equals("+")){
                System.out.print(num1+num2);}

            if (inString.equals("-")){
                System.out.print(num1-num2);}

            if (inString.equals("*")||(inString.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))){
                System.out.print(num1*num2);}

            if (inString.equals("/")){
                System.out.print(num1/num2);}   }//If Float
}//Public Void Calculator

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat){
            calculator();   
            System.out.println("Do you wish to repeat(y/n)?");
            String answer = userInput.next();


                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                    repeat = true;
                } else { repeat = false;}}
     }//Main
}//Class
```

I am beginner so please bear with me :^) . Thanks.

Comment: I'm debugging your code, didn't finished it yet. I think it's something with userInput.hasNextFloat()

Comment: also: turn some of those
if ( x == a ) {} if ( x == b ){} options into: if ( x == a) {} else if ( x == b ) {} 
It 'll make your code easier to debug. It might be because you didn't correctly calculate the behavior of a used next or hasNext call.
if you add a print statement at the end of calculator, does that show before the pause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of this line:

```
if (userInput.hasNextFloat()){
```

The `hasNext...()` methods in `Scanner` are *blocking* methods. They block if there is no input other than white space in the scanner, waiting for *something* to be entered. As soon as something real (not spaces or newlines) is entered, then they check whether it is a float, an int or whatever, and return a true/false reply to you.

After you finish an integer calculation, your program calls `hasNextFloat()`, and therefore, it blocks, waiting until you enter something. If that something is not a float, it will return false, and the `if` will not work.

You can experiment a little and see:

- If you run your program and start with a float (say, `17.2`), the program will show you the `Do you wish to repeat?` question after it calculates the result.
- If you run your program and start with an int, and then, after you get the result, enter a float, it will print the `:` that is asking you for the float operator.

So basically, that should not be an `if`. It should be an `else if` structure.

Comment: Wow spot on. You really know when to use if and else if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `else if` instead of `if` to check userInput.hasNextFloat().

Your code sample will look like.

```
if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
        int num1 = userInput.nextInt();
        ....
        ....
        ....

    } else if (userInput.hasNextFloat()){
        float num1 = userInput.nextFloat();
        ....
        ....
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextInt()` and remove the `if(hasNextFloat())` part. And use the `Number` class because it accepts both ints and floats:

```
if (userInput.hasNext()) {
    Number num1 = userInput.nextByte();
    System.out.print(":");
    String inString = userInput.next();
    System.out.print(":");
    Number num2 = userInput.nextByte();
    System.out.print("=");

    switch (inString) {
        case "+":
            System.out.print(num1.doubleValue() + num2.doubleValue());
            break;

        case "-":
            System.out.print(num1.doubleValue() - num2.doubleValue());
            break;

        case "*":
        case "x":
        case "X":
            System.out.print(num1.doubleValue() * num2.doubleValue());
            break;

        case "/":
            double intTofloat = num1.doubleValue() / num2.doubleValue();
            System.out.println(intTofloat);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println(INVALID OPERATOR!);
            break;
    }
}
```